# typescript unhandledRejection Promise

Tags: typescript, promise

I call an external process using typescript, like this:

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'
execSync('/my/executable/here')
```

But the executable is has an error in it, which is causing execSync to fail. Is there a way to catch the error (as a string) and print it or assign it to variable?

I tried doing this but the code still keeps saying "unhandledRejection  Promise"

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    execSync('/my/executable/here')
})
promise.then(result => console.log('CALL RAN'))
promise.catch(error => console.log('FOUND ERROR'))
```

The error that I get looks like this:

```
2019-11-26T00:17:23.060 ERROR (pid:36622) [server] - unhandledRejection  Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Command failed: /my/executable/here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the error and then resolve/reject as appropriate.

e.g.

```
// Try to use const where possible
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {  
    execSync('/my/executable/here');
    resolve();
  } catch(e) {
    reject(e);
  }
})

// Chain the promise handlers
promise
  .then(result => console.log('CALL RAN'))
  .catch(error => console.log('FOUND ERROR'));
```

Comment: I think that did the trick. Thanks! I'm still getting an error from the server that's calling this code (in this case, coc.nvim (https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim). I may have to talk to the maintainers about it.

Theoretically though, this should completely squash the error at its root, right? If you know why I might still be getting issues from the server, I'd be grateful to hear your thoughts.

Comment: If the call is fully synchronous, then this should catch any exception it throws. There may be problems if they spawn another process and/or use something like `setTimeout` internally.